# Extension class corresponding to Semi-abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This question is related to the answer of this post by abx: [Curves and semi-abelian varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425669/curves-and-semi-abelian-varieties).

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve, and let $C$ be the nodal curve obtained by identifying the points $p_1,p_2\in X$.
I wonder how one can show that the  element in $$JX\cong\text{Pic}^0(JX) \cong \text{Ext}(JX, \mathbb{G}_m)$$ corresponding to the extension $$0\to \mathbb{G}_m\to JC \to JX\to 0,$$ is precisely $[p_1]-[p_2]\in JX$. If there exists a good reference for how to do such computations this would also be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The line bundle corresponding to the principal $\mathbb G_m$ bundle $JC\rightarrow JX$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal Hom (P_{p_2}, P_{p_1})\cong P_{p_1}\otimes P_{p_2}^{-1}$. Here $P\rightarrow X\times JX$ is a universal line bundle. Now if we pull back the line bundle $P_{p_1}\otimes P_{p_2}^{-1}$ via the inclusion $X\hookrightarrow JX$ we get $\mathcal O_X(p_1-p_2)$, by the definition of the universal bundle. The references that I know are Cyril Dsouza's thesis and the paper by Oda and Seshadri.